# Typescript :: namespacing functions within a class?

Tags: typescript

Assume a simple class like so:

```
class Simple {
  private _transactions: [];
  makeTransaction() { ... }
  revertTransaction() { ... }
  // some other methods as well...
}

let obj = new Simple();
obj.makeTransaction(...);
obj.makeTransaction(...);
obj.revertTransaction(...);
```

Now, I want to expose some more methods related to reporting and I would like to group them like so:

```
obj.reports.allTransactions();
obj.reports.reveretedTransactions();
obj.reports.clearedTransactions();
```

These methods will be using the private variables within the `Simple` class itself to return some reports.

I have used the following to achieve this:

```
class Simple {
  private _test = () => { return this._transaction }
  reports = {
    getAll: this._test
  }
}
```

This works, but it has a couple of downsides:

1. It forces me to declare all required functions as part of the class itself and then reference them in the `reports` object again.
2. Typescript shows me that `obj.reports.getAll` is a property, although I can invoke it as a function too. Even so, I don't get the correct function signature hint.
3. It forces me to use arrow functions (closures) needlessly.

Is there a better way of doing the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class for the `reports` object:

```
class Reports {
    private _transactions: any[];

    constructor(transactions: any[]) {
        this._transactions = transactions;
    }

    getAll() {
        return this._transactions;
    }
}

class Simple {
    private _transactions: any[];
    public reports: Reports;

    constructor() {
        this._transactions = [];
        this.reports = new Reports(this._transactions);
    }

    makeTransaction() {}
    revertTransaction() { }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Reports%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_transactions%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(transactions%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._transactions%20%3D%20transactions%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getAll()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._transactions%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Simple%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_transactions%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20reports%3A%20Reports%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._transactions%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.reports%20%3D%20new%20Reports(this._transactions)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20makeTransaction()%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20revertTransaction()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A))

---

#### Edit

You can also expose `reports` as a type:

```
interface Reports {
    getAll(): any[];
}

class Simple {
    private _transactions: any[];
    public reports: Reports;

    constructor() {
        this._transactions = [];
        this.reports = {
            getAll: () => {
                return this._transactions;
            }
        }
    }

    makeTransaction() {}
    revertTransaction() { }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Reports%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20getAll()%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Simple%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_transactions%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20reports%3A%20Reports%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._transactions%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.reports%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getAll%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._transactions%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20makeTransaction()%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20revertTransaction()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A))

---

#### 2nd Edit

Another option is to seperate the reports into a different class but to have the `Simple` instance as its member with all members of the instance as public.
If you then turn `Simple` into an interface you can hide those public members:

```
class Reports {
    private _simple: SimpleImpl;

    constructor(simple: SimpleImpl) {
        this._simple = simple;
    }

    getAll() {
        return this._simple.transactions;
    }
}

interface Simple {
    makeTransaction();
    revertTransaction();
}

class SimpleImpl implements Simple {
    public transactions: any[];
    public reports: Reports;

    constructor() {
        this.transactions = [];
        this.reports = new Reports(this);
    }

    makeTransaction() {}
    revertTransaction() {}
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Reports%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_simple%3A%20SimpleImpl%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(simple%3A%20SimpleImpl)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._simple%20%3D%20simple%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getAll()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._simple.transactions%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Simple%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20makeTransaction()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20revertTransaction()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20SimpleImpl%20implements%20Simple%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20transactions%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20reports%3A%20Reports%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.transactions%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.reports%20%3D%20new%20Reports(this)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20makeTransaction()%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20revertTransaction()%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A))

If only `Reports` class and the `Simple` interface are exposed then the public members are only visible to the instances of `Reports`.

Comment: Hmm.. Though this does work, it splits implementation between two classes.. The example I gave was a stripped down one.. In my actual use-case, I have about 10 private fields and their reference is not constant (clear() => this._list = []).. But if there is no other way to go.. Ill accept this answer.. =)

Comment: `You can also expose reports as a type`.. THIS! is what i needed! thanks a lot mate.. this worked just fine.. no need for separate classes sharing data.. and the closure maintains the `this` reference.. awesome!

Comment: If this class gets too big and/or the logic in `Reports` gets too long then it's probably better to separate it into a different class (avoiding "bad smells"). I updated my answer with a nice way of doing that.